# Render Chinese characters from encoded CSV

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file whose fields contain encoding for chinese characters:

```
example cell value: \u53ef\u7231\u7684\u7cd6\u679c\u5c0f\u5e97
```

How can I save this file (as .xlsx or xls) to properly render the characters?

Answer (score 0):

First I input the data into cell **A1**
Then use *Text-to-Columns* to split the data into **B1** through **H1**.

Then in **B2** enter the formula:

```
=chrr(MID(B1,2,9999))
```

and copy across.

This uses this VBA *UDF()*:

```
Public Function chrr(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long

    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(s)
    chrr = ChrW(i)
End Function
```

This results in:

[image]

Note I pick a font the supports UniCode.
Then save in a standard Excel format like **.xlsm**.  Naturally, if you have many records in the **.csv** file, you would "package" the results differently, pack the characters into a single cell, or store the results in a row or in a column, etc.

*Please let me know if the characters are proper.*